# Get the last character of string inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, codeigniter

The question required me to get the first char from the first word in array with the last char from the second word in an array I can just get the first char but my problem is with the second one like:

```
var array1 = ["hello", "sam", "aola"];
var result = [];
  const nextString =array1[1][array1[1].length - 1];  
  array1.map(function(currentString){
  result.push(currentString.charAt(0)+nextString)

});

 console.log(result);
```

here is my code give me this result: `[ 'hm', 'sm', 'am' ]`

but it expect to get this result :`[ 'hm', 'sa', 'ao' ]`

So please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const array = ["hello", "sam", "aola"];

const result = array.map( (element, index, array) => {
  return element.charAt(0) + array[(index + 1) % array.length].slice(-1)
 } );

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Really really thanksss a lot JohannesKantz